# Install repo fork using el-get

Tags: package-repositories, powerline

[This](https://github.com/Dewdrops/powerline) is what I am trying to install but I keep running into no 'powerline-themes'. I have only started using Emacs yesterday, so can someone please point out what is going on behind the scenes and why is it failing?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't tell you anything unless you give us details on what you are actually doing, and *how* it is failing. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What @phils said. Unless you provide useful details, this question is too broad to be helpful, and will likely be closed.

Comment: Open the messages buffer and see if you can locate the errors. The other option is to ask the powerline-themes author on github directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an el-get recipe. You can create a directory to save your custom recipes and tell el-get about it:

```
(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-recipes")
```

Then create the recipe for your repo:

```
(:name powerline-themes
       :website "http://github.com/Dewdrops/powerline"
       :description "My powerline themes fork"

       :type github
       :pkgname "Dewdrops/powerline"
       :features powerline-themes
       :depends powerline)
```

and save in your `~/.emacs.d/el-get-recipes` with the name `powerline-themes.rcp`. Now your custom recipe should be available in `el-get-install`.

I'm not using el-get and I couldn't test the recipe above, so you might have to change some value in there.

Comment: The `:pkgname` should be `"Dewdrops/powerline"`